# Как отрисовать элементы сайта в canvas?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, canvas

Есть сайты которые полностью нарисованы в canvas.

Например у меня есть блок который имеет стили, анимации, реагирует на действие пользователя.

```
<div class="block">
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Идея в том чтобы нарисовать этот блок в canvas и потом изменять изображение.

Нужно рисовать все вручную или есть другие методы?

Может есть готовые библиотеки которые это делают?

Comment: Это не очень простое дело. Зачем вам это надо? Например, нарисовать `<input type="text" />` - не самая тривиальная задача.

Comment: Для создания анимации.

Comment: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation

Comment: Какой именно анимации? Возможно, вашу анимацию можно решить через CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Подобное уже реализовано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10936664/7388307). Можно протестировать [онлайн](https://codepen.io/beben-koben/pen/GgJxrW)

```
(function(d, w){
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var FONT_SIZE = 14;
    var canvas = d.getElementById("world");
    var dom = d.getElementById("dom");
    var button = d.getElementById("button_change");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = 
        "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='"+WIDTH+"px' height='"+HEIGHT+"px'>" +
            "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font: "+FONT_SIZE+"px sans-serif;'>" +
                    dom.innerHTML+
                "</div>" +
            "</foreignObject>" +
        "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            dom.style.display = "none";
            button.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee, false);
        }, false);
    }, false);
    img.src = url;
    ctx.canvas.width = WIDTH;
    ctx.canvas.height= HEIGHT;
})(document, window);
```

Comment: в codepen на 22 строчке не опечатка ?

Comment: @MaximLensky нет, оно же работает... Вероятно, код с времен, когда стандарт URL.revokeObjectURL() не был реализован браузерами повсеместно